# sorting array only pulling one integer from table

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, innerhtml

I believe the solution is in the innerhtml but have yet to come up with a solution. I'm pretty new to coding and have had some outside help getting thus far, but as you can see something is wrong with the array because it is only pulling the first integer of each number in the table body. I'm sure this an easy fix.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var people, asc1 = 1,
            asc2 = 1,
            asc3 = 1,
        asc4 = 1,
        asc5 = 1,
        asc6 = 1,
        asc7 = 1,
        asc8 = 1,
        asc9 = 1,
        asc10 = 1,
        asc11 = 1
        asc12 = 1;
        window.onload = function () {
            people = document.getElementById("people");
        }
    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
            var rows = tbody.rows,
                rlen = rows.length,
                arr = new Array(),
                i, j, cells, clen;
            // fill the array with values from the table
            for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
                cells = rows[i].cells;
                clen = cells.length;
                arr[i] = new Array();
                for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
                }
            }
            // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order     (asc)
            arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
            });
            // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
            for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
                rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: none;
        }
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 4px 16px;
            font-family: Times New Roman;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #C8C8C8;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1;">Player</th>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1;">Team</th>
                <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Role</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 3, asc4); asc4 *= -1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">KDA</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 4, asc5); asc5 *= -1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1;">Kills</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 5, asc6); asc6 *= -1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1;">Deaths</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 6, asc7); asc7 *= -1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1;">Assists</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 7, asc8); asc8 *= -1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1;">KP(%)</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 8, asc9); asc9 *= -1; asc10 = 1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1;">CS(Total)</th>  
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 9, asc10); asc10 *= -1; asc11 = 1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1;">CS(p/m)</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 10, asc11); asc11 *= -1; asc12 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1;">Gold(~Thousands)</th>
        <th onclick="sort_table(people, 11, asc12); asc12 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc8 = 1; asc9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc11 =1;">Games Played</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="people">
            <tr>

        <tr><td>Anivia HD</td><td>Apox</td><td>Mid</td><td>1.1</td><td>9</td>  <td>16</td><td>8</td><td>64.5</td><td>664</td><td>6.2</td><td>33</td><td>4</td></tr>   
        <tr><td>Zeabard</td><td>Apox</td><td>ADC</td><td>1.6</td><td>5</td><td>12</td><td>10</td><td>61.75</td><td>611</td><td>5.8</td><td>32</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>MurkHexis</td><td>Apox</td><td>Support</td><td>2.8</td><td>1</td><td>14</td><td>13</td><td>71.25</td><td>60</td><td>0.6</td><td>23</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>JMLCN</td><td>Apox</td><td>Jungle</td><td>0.8</td><td>6</td><td>20</td><td>11</td><td>78.25</td><td>255</td><td>2.5</td><td>28</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tlaliquid sen</td><td>Apox</td><td>Top</td><td>0.8</td><td>5</td><td>22</td><td>12</td><td>62.25</td><td>627</td><td>5.8</td><td>31</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Higginbottomz</td><td>NVA</td><td>Mid</td><td>11.3</td><td>7</td><td>3</td><td>20</td><td>48.5</td><td>400</td><td>5.9</td><td>24</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>iFeederDog</td><td>NVA</td><td>Jungle</td><td>17.5</td><td>9</td><td>0</td><td>26</td><td>63.5</td><td>288</td><td>4.3</td><td>26</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>s Herny</td><td>NVA</td><td>Top</td><td>13.8</td><td>16</td><td>3</td><td>20</td><td>65.5</td><td>423</td><td>6.5</td><td>28</td><td>2</td></tr>

 </tr>
```

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? What the code is supposed to do and what really happens?

Comment: This code is for a statistical table that sorts in ascending/descending order based off all data in table. The problem is it is only pulling the first integer of each numerical value from the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma here : asc10 = 1, asc11 = 1 asc12 = 1;

A lot of things can be done better but your main problem is that you are sorting strings and this is the reason the sorting of numeric fields is not correct. You have to cast the strings into integers before use arr.sort().

Use parseInt() for the columns that are filled with integers before sorting them with arr.sort(). Because you see them as numbers but really they are strings for the sort method so you should turn them into numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the comma mishap! Like I said my coding experience is very limited, and I have had a lot of help thus far. With that being said I'm not sure what you mean by casting the string into integers first.

Comment: So parseInt() should go before arr.sort? I've tried using parseInt() but I guess im inputting it in the wrong position in the code.

Comment: Before. So the sort method could sort integers not strings.

Comment: Thank you, gave you the check. I'll try to figure it out from here.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
                cells = rows[i].cells;
                clen = cells.length;
                arr[i] = new Array();
                for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
      cells[j].innerHTML = parseInt(cells[j].innerHTML, 10) + 1;       Am I on the right track?